# BIND 9 Slave server forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding

I was curious about a small thing.

Right now I have my local DNS servers (NS01 and SAN01) NS01 is the master and SAN01 is the slave. NS01 forwards all DNS requests to the gateway (PFsense) which then forwards them to OpenDNS.

Should I have my slave just forward its queries to the master or the gateway also?

Or is there a better way, topology wise to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both master and slave should forward directly to the target, which in your case is OpenDNS. It makes no sense to bounce it around the way you're doing.

Comment: ok, I was I had read somewhere that what I did was a good idea. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I have found `forwarder` option only work with master, when i configure in `slave` it didn't work, anythought?